# ExpressionEngine, Safecracker form embed select box value in URL in safecracker form

Tags: url, embed, expressionengine, safecracker

I have an embed in my safecracker form.
Embed has a select box and can select a name of 
a Tea.

I want to send name of the Tea with safecracker URL to next page.

This is the code:

```
{exp:safecracker channel="blending_log"  return="sthome/blending/ENTRY_ID" dynamic_title="     [selected_tea]_[organic_or_conventional][date_time][agent_number]"}
<h3>Select and enter data</h3>
{embed="stembeds/.blending_select_tea"}

{!--------Receive data to create value--------}
<input type="hidden" name="title" value="" />
<br /><br />
Organic Or Conventional:
 {field:org_con}

 Agent Number:
 {field:agent_number}

{!-----END Receive data to create lot number-------}
```

The embed is:
{embed="stembeds/.blending_select_tea"}

This is the code in embed:

```
<select name="selected_tea">
<option selected="selected" >Select a Tea</option>
{exp:channel:entries channel="tea_herbs" order_by="title" sort="asc"}

<option name={title} id={entry_id} value={url_title}>{title}</option>

{/exp:channel:entries} 

</select>
```

I want to select tea from embed and I want to send the Tea name with safecracker URL:

```
{exp:safecracker channel="blending_log" dynamic_title="[selected_tea]_[organic_or_conventional][date_time][agent_number]"   return="sthome/blending2_nimmi/ENTRY_ID"}
```

Please help me to solve this issue.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have a text field in your "blending_log" channel with the name "selected_tea" - otherwise SafeCracker won't save that value.

Your embed should look like this:

```
<select name="selected_tea">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Select a Tea</option>
    {exp:channel:entries channel="tea_herbs" order_by="title" sort="asc" dynamic="no" disable="member_data|pagination|categories"}
    <option value="{url_title}">{title}</option>
    {/exp:channel:entries} 
</select>
```

Comment: Wow! It works. Thank you very much. Simply amazing. How did you master ExpressionEngine and all the relevant plugins etc?  Amazing. Thank you very much. If there is a way to give you points I will give highest points.